# Alternate ways for Logging the Response Object in Golang

Tags: http, go, logging, response

I am making a logging package for microservices in Go.
I am new to Go and was not able to find any alternate method for properly logging the response body end to end.
It goes like-

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
```

and

```
http.get("some url to hit the API")
```

I have picked up my testing in an open github project where I have the first way which helped me logging the request object.
I am not sure if I can use the same method the get the whole response object with status code,time, response and other usual configs which I can retrieve from.
I have to make a json string from the object and send it to an index I created on elasticsearch.

Is there a way to get an response object saved without knowing which url was being hit?
Please let me know if any other details are needed.

I am using gorilla/mux for setting up my server.